# Nginx fastcgi cache URL matching homepage

Tags: nginx, caching, fastcgi

I want to cache all pages except of homepage with Nginx Fastcgi cache. I am not able to achieve this. The site is running Wordpress.

How do I match the URL of the homepage?

```
  set $fastcgi_skipcache 0;

  if ($uri = "/") {
        set $fastcgi_skipcache 1;
  }
```

Then in location ~ .php block I have this setup

```
fastcgi_cache_bypass $fastcgi_skipcache;
fastcgi_no_cache $fastcgi_skipcache;
```